# How do I find the probability distribution of the random variable $g(X)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} , -\infty < x < \infty$

Let $g(x)= \begin{cases} 1 ;x>0 \\ \frac{1}{2} ; x=0 \\ -1 ; x<0 \end{cases}$

How do i find the probability distribution function  of $g(X)$?

My attempt so far

Let $Y = g(X)$ be a random variable.

Case 1: Let $y=-1$ then

$P\{Y = -1 \} = \int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx $

I think my approach is absolutely wrong.How do i proceed ?

Comment: what is "pdf" ?

Comment: $$E[g(X)]=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{X>0\}}]-E[\mathbf{1}_{\{X<0\}}]=P(X>0)-P(X<0)=0.5-0.5=0$$

Comment: @psl2Z  probability distribution function

Comment: @SnoopSn I dont understand. Can you elaborate it a bit.Why are we finding the Expectation- it  has yet not been introduced in the chapter. Maybe the author wants us to do the problem witout using it

Comment: The defintion of probability distribution function is $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(g(X)\leq x)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths . Your approach is not wrong. What you want to calculate is $\mathbb P(Y= -1)$ and $\mathbb P(Y=+1)$. The RV is binomial. Just one thing: $\mathbb P(Y=-1)=\int_{-\infty}^{\color{red}{0}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx$.

Comment: With a similar approach. Or deduce it from $1=\mathbb P(Y=-1)+\mathbb P(Y=1)$.

Comment: @ThirstForMaths . I see the answer is accepted . You got it now ?

Comment: Yes i did.thanks for the help .

Comment: Thanks for deleting a few comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(Y=1)=\mathbb{P}(X>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

$\mathbb{P}(Y=1/2)=0$

$\mathbb{P}(Y=-1)=\mathbb{P}(X<0)=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)dx$

Comment: Thanks ! On behalf of OP.

Comment: Yeah i got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

As $X$ follows the standard normal distribution, I like to further simplify SacAndSac's answer for more readability.

This is not a new answer but a simplification only. I add it for more info.

$$
P(Y = 1) = P(X > 0) = {1 \over 2}
$$
$$
P(Y = 0) = 0
$$
$$
P(Y = -1) = P(X < 0) = {1 \over 2}
$$
where we have used the information that $X$ follows the standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

Hence, $Y$ is a discrete random variable with mass points $1$ and $-1$ and having equal probabilities ${1 \over 2}$ and ${1 \over 2}$ for the two mass points.